# Limpar input e inserir novo valor ao mesmo

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

O combobox destacado em vermelho ao ser selecionado, dispara uma ação no jquery para pegar valores dos outros inputs e adicionar no input em azul(tipo hidden, mas esta text para voces verem o que esta acontecendo) até aí tudo bem, problema que se for clicado novamente ao invés de atualizar o valor do input azul, ele esta acrescentando novamente os novos valores aos valores antigos. Já tentei user empty e nada, ja tentei limpar a o valor do input azul e acrescentar novamente os valores e nada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
      var scp_opts = {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    selectFirst: false,
    appentTo: '#input_configurations_plan',
    source: function(request, response){
       let plan  = $(".form_union_plans:last").val();
       let split = plan.split("|");

      $.ajax({
        url: getUrl + "filter/code_per_plan",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:{'term' : request.term, 'table' : split[1] }
      }).done(function( codePlan ){

          if( codePlan.length > 0 ){

             codePlan = codePlan.split( ',' );

             response( $.each( codePlan, function( key, item ){
                return({
                    label: item  
                });

             }));
          }
      });
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
       var plan   = $(".form_union_plans:last").val();
       var split  = plan.split("|"); 
       var ch     = $(".insert-factor-multiplier:last").val();
       var number = $(".insert-ch:last").val();
       var  values = '';
      $.ajax({
        url: getUrl + "filter/value_code_per_plan",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'term' : ui.item.value, 'table': split[1]}
      }).done(function( response ){
        var code   = $(".search-code-plan:last").val();
        if( response.value != "" ){
         $(event.target).closest('tr').find('td .insert-value-code').val( response.value.replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1.") );                
         var money = response.value.replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1.");                
        }

          values = plan +'|'+ ch +'|'+ number +'|'+ code +'|'+ money;

        if( ( count++ ) == 0 ){

         $(event.target).closest('tr').find('td .form_union_plans').val( values ); 

        }else{
          $(event.target).closest('tr').find('td .form_union_plans').val("");  
          $(event.target).closest('tr').find('td .form_union_plans').val( values);  
        }

      });

    }
```

}

Comment: E o que é `values`... Não seria esse o problema? Você não deve estar reiniciando seu values...

Comment: @fernandosavio values é somatorio de todos os inputs. Como faria para reinicia-los?

Comment: Você consegue prover um [mcve]? Seu problema foi bem explicado, porém você não mostra quase nada de código e o que você mostra claramente não é a fonte do problema. Qualquer dúvida sempre tem o: [ask]

Comment: já tentei dessa forma @Sam e não funcionou

Comment: Tem que mostrar o código inteiro. Só com o trecho informado não tem como dizer nada.

Comment: Editei @Sam a pergunta com trecho do código, ao selecionar o select ele joga no ultimo input dois valores e depois quando é escolhido o código em vermelho da imagem ele acrescenta o restante dos valores.

Comment: @Sam Mas aí não vai funcionar também, já tentei isso. Teria que limpar o valor do input FORM_UNION_PLANS e atualizar ele com os valores novamente. Eu consigo limpar e coloquei uma função setTimeout para pegar os valores novamente e inserir, mas eles estão indo duplicados novamente :(

Comment: O que é esse `#input_configurations_plan`?

Comment: @Sam é o ID do body da table, onde estão esses inputs, para atribuir cada nova linha dentro das trs! Eu não sei porque ele esta deixando o VALUE vazio, mas na hora de inserir os dados novamente ele pega o anterior, mas como se ele foi " esvaziado " ?

Comment: Certeza que o problema é nesse `plan`... Aqui `var plan   = $(".form_union_plans:last").val();` vc pega o valor do último e depois faz um split pra mandar pro AJAX, e no done o `plan` continua o mesmo.

Comment: @Sam eu mudei o VAR PLAN que voce citou e passei outro valor de class $(".rule-choose-plan-doctor:last").val(), substituindo a union_plans e funcionou, com isso pude até retirar o if final. Obrigado aí pela paciência e ajuda. Como faço para sinaliza-la como resolvida e marcar voce como autor da ajuda? Sou novo aqui e não sei muito bem ainda mexer no stack

Comment: Legal que resolveu. Cara, ou vc deixa como está ou pode colocar uma resposta vc mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido alterando var plan = $(".form_union_plans:last").val(); por var plan = $(".rule-choose-plan-doctor:last").val(); Anteriormente a cada clique estava pegando todo o valor de form_union_plans e inserindo nele mesmo, esse foi o erro! Com o valor da class rule-choose-plan-doctor ele altera form_union_plans somente com os dados que precisam. Obrigado @Sam